# Fail to return a string from a method

Tags: java, string, oop, get, return

> The constructor takes in  a String and store it in the local variable `modifier`. Then i wanted to return `modifier` by `getModifer()` method. However the method couldn't return the `String` passed in from the constructor. Please help me to spot out the problem. thanks!

```
private String modifer;

public UMLAccessModifer(String input)
{   
    /**
     * Takes in the type of access modifier.
     */

    this.modifer = input;

    if(input.toLowerCase().contains("public")){
        this.modifer = "public";

    }
    else if(input.toLowerCase().contains("private")){
        this.modifer = "private";

    }
    else if(input.toLowerCase().contains("protected")){
        this.modifer = "protected";

    }
    else {
        this.modifer = "private";

    }

}

public String getModifer() {
    /**
     * Returns the string of Modifier.
     */
    return modifer;
```

Comment: Be more precise with the error you have. A small example of input/output would be useful.

Comment: what is the error and what is your input ??

Comment: What did you use for `input`, what did you get back and what did you expect?

Comment: Problem doesn't seem to come from your code. Check you're effectively passing a string when you construct your object.

Comment: I expected get the string of public. Input is the user input from GUI, but it didn't return anything. Console panel shows the error that null pointer exception.

Comment: @Mong Post the relevant code.

Comment: `couldn't return the String passed in from the constructor` Why couldnt you what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat simplified version of your code, which works:

```
public class UMLAccessModifier
{
    private String modifier;

    public UMLAccessModifier(String input)
    {   
        if(input.toLowerCase().contains("public"))
        {
            modifier = "public";
        }

        else if(input.toLowerCase().contains("protected"))
        {
            modifier = "protected";
        }

        else 
        {
            modifer = "private";
        }
    }

    public String getModifier() 
    {
        return modifier;
    }
}
```

Not sure what you're doing, but `getModifier()` will definitely return `modifier`.  Odds are you're not passing what you think you are, or you're in some way transforming the return value at some point, but I assure you that a `String` will be returned.

The only thing that I can think of is that you're expecting the string to be returned from just calling the constructor, which does not happen.  You need to call `getModifier()` from the object that you get from the constructor, ie:

```
UMLAccessModifier test =  new UMLAccessModifier("garbage");
System.out.println(test.getModifier());
//prints: private
```